# Using Selenium to automatically select a date in a datepicker

Tags: c#, selenium, css-selectors

I am having issues with trying to automate a test to select a date from a datepicker (without a date input field). I have searched and seen several examples, one specifically states you can use it with By.CssSelector, i am unsure however what exactly needs to be specified in this.

This is the HTML:

```
<td class="dpTD" onmouseout="this.className=&quot;dpTD&quot;;" 
onmouseover="this.className=&quot;dpTDHover&quot;;" 
onclick="updateDateField('03/04/2012', '2', '3', '3', '2012');">3</td>
```

This is the C#:

```
WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("inputtexthere")).Click();
```

Comment: Can we see more markup, e.g. the table which contains this td?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can select it by its class:

```
WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".dpTD")).Click();
```

Or if there's more than one cell with that class, try narrowing it down with `:contains()`:

```
WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".dpTD:contains('3')")).Click();
```

Or even an attribute substring selector:

```
WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".dpTD[onclick*=updateDateField]")).Click();
```

I'm just throwing suggestions out here as there's not enough markup to work with. If you've worked with CSS, you can use almost any selector with Selenium.

Comment: Thank you! Using the attribute substring selector has fixed my issue.